# How to up navigate from fragment activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, appcompatactivity

Hi I am having trouble while going back to parent activity from fragment activity. I want back arrow at top left corner inside the action bar.

I am able to show it in action bar activity using this code

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

But I am not able to do it in tabbed activity's fragment.

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Please Help me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this inside `onCreate()` of your tabbed activity,

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

And for navigating back, you need to override following method in your tabbed activity.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Happy coding.

Comment: It is not giving me any error just showing that it may cause null pointer exception and when I click on up navigation arrow it does nothing

Comment: since when you are getting this warning? I mean what part you added in you code and this happen?

Comment: After I added fabmenu

Comment: Ok I got the solution I had set return false in onCreateOptionsMenu. That's why it was not working

Answer (score 0):

Add this method to your activity to navigate back.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();// or the action you want to do eg. Removing fragment
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: The back arrow button appears with this line`getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);`

Comment: make sure you have setted the actionbar with `setSupportActionbar(toolbar)`

Comment: What is toolbar here?

Comment: toolbar is instance of toolbar which you added in xml layout